# What package do I need to install to develop plugins for gedit?

Tags: python, gedit, pygi

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with python 2.7.3 and PyGObject and I'd like to develop plugins for Gedit in python. I found a simple looking tutorial for this sort of thing [here](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo).

According to the tutorial, I need the Gedit module to interact with the plugin interface:

```
from gi.repository import GObject, Gedit
```

I keep getting an import error when trying to import the Gedit module. So, my question is: what package do I need to install to get this module?

I've tried: `gedit-dev` , `gedit-plugins`

Edit: Here is the full traceback for the above statement:

```
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gedit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Gedit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the typelib you need for developing gedit plugins is contained in the gedit package itself.

```
$ apt-file search Gedit-3.0.typelib
gedit: /usr/lib/gedit/girepository-1.0/Gedit-3.0.typelib
```

But when using python either interactively or from a script, `from gi.repository import Gedit` searches `/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/` rather than `/usr/lib/gedit/girepository-1.0`. That is the cause of the import error.

You'll need to create the appropriate .plugin and .py files in ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins and run your code by selecting the plugin in the gedit preferences dialog.

Answer (score 4):

I get the same error as you if I run the plugin code directly without Gedit.

As it is described in the manual you linked, you need to make a .plugin file for your plugin code.
Place your plugin code and the .plugin file into  ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins. 
Restart Gedit.
Open Gedit > Edit > Preferences > Plugins and look for your plugin.
Set the checkmark for your plugin.
Your plugin shoud run now using the Gedit code.

To check for errors in your plugin, start gedit from a console.

Answer (score 1):

An import error for `Gedit` may indicate that `GtkSource-3.0.typelib` is missing or not installed correctly.

Typical symptoms are in addition that you can't load several plugins (not only the one you develop yourself), and that you get warnings when starting `gedit` from the command line (seen on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy). You can fix this by installing the missing package:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
```

See also: [Warnings while launching gedit from the Ubuntu terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369915/warnings-while-launching-gedit-from-the-ubuntu-terminal)

Also note that the plugins for GEdit v3 use `python3` instead of version 2.7.x of Python.