# Warnings while launching gedit from the Ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, gedit

I am facing these warnings while launching gedit from my terminal. Eventually gedit starts, but with these lines of warning every time when I launch gedit:

```
(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:138:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:138:24: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:138:28: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:138:32: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2237:26: 'none' is not a valid color name

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2264:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2264:24: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2264:28: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2264:32: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: sidebar.css:22:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: sidebar.css:40:18: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: sidebar.css:40:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

** (gedit:3830): WARNING **: Could not load Gedit repository: Typelib file for namespace 'GtkSource', version '3.0' not found

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(gedit:3830): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Updating gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 solved the problem for me; the errors no longer appear.

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
```

Comment: yes it worked Mr.Kyle Chadha...

Answer (score 1):

Normally those warning indicates the poor development of the application, but are normally ignored by programmers. Is not a critical problem and can be safely ignored if the program works as intended.

BTW, the problem seems to be with the theme that doesn't declare `px` in their css. You could go and edit the `siderbar.css` and make the corrections in line 40 and 22. In `gtk-wirdgets.css` line 2264, 2237 and 138. There are multiple instances. That is for the *"Theme parsing error"*, also seems that you miss the SessionManager package and GtkSource isn't version 3.

Comment: where can i find sidebar.css and gtk-wirdgets.css

Comment: You can use `locate sidebar.css` to find it fast. Take into account the name of your theme so you don't modify some theme that it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using `gksudo` instad of `sudo` will stop these warnings from comming!

take a look here [difference between gksudo and sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163884/difference-between-gksudo-and-sudo)