# root issues in softwarecenter, synaptic and update manager

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

i have a notebook samsung ativ 2  and ubuntu 12.04 precise, cinnamon desktop. after logging in today my update manager, synaptic and ubuntu softwarecenter stopped working. synaptic i can only launch from terminal the others from panel.when choosing to update, nothing happens. same thing when trying to install programms from syn. or softw.center.when launching softwarec. from terminal i get:

```
marcus@ddddddddd:~$ software-center
2013-11-10 22:30:46,206 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-11-10 22:30:46,217 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True

(software-center:4772): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: softwarecenter.css:34:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(software-center:4772): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: softwarecenter.css:34:22: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(software-center:4772): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: softwarecenter.css:56:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(software-center:4772): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: softwarecenter.css:56:22: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(software-center:4772): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: softwarecenter.css:60:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(software-center:4772): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: softwarecenter.css:60:22: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
2013-11-10 22:30:46,977 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-11-10 22:30:47,320 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2013-11-10 22:30:48,057 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2013-11-10 22:31:00,646 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/utils.py', 201, 'get_title_from_html')'
2013-11-10 22:31:00,645 - root - WARNING - failed to parse: '<div style="background-color: #161513; width:1680px; height:200px;">
 <div style="background: url('/site_media/exhibits/2013/09/AAMFP_Leaderboard_700x200_1.jpg') top left no-repeat; width:700px; height:200px;"></div>
</div>' ('ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 70: ordinal not in range(128))
2013-11-10 22:31:02,268 - softwarecenter.db.update - INFO - skipping region restricted app: 'Comentarios Web' (not whitelisted)
2013-11-10 22:31:02,769 - softwarecenter.db.update - INFO - skipping region restricted app: 'reEarCandy' (not whitelisted)
2013-11-10 22:31:04,821 - softwarecenter.db.update - INFO - skipping region restricted app: 'Flaggame' (not whitelisted)
2013-11-10 22:31:05,622 - softwarecenter.db.update - INFO - skipping region restricted app: 'Bulleti d'esquerra de Calonge i Sant Antoni ' (not whitelisted)
2013-11-10 22:31:08,352 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
2013-11-10 22:31:08,353 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - reopen() database
2013-11-10 22:31:08,353 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-11-10 22:33:32,319 - softwarecenter.backend - WARNING - _on_trans_error: org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.72'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
2013-11-10 22:36:01,818 - softwarecenter.backend - WARNING - daemon dies, ignoring: <AptTransaction object at 0x48e4b40 (aptdaemon+client+AptTransaction at 0x645aaa0)> exit-failed
2013-11-10 22:36:01,820 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
```

Comment: I don't see any `ERROR` but a bunch of `WARNING`'s and `INFO`'s. If it's about "Theme parsing error" see this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/369920/169736. Can you do `sudo apt-get check` and `sudo apt-get update`??

Comment: i just tried the update manager and got this:W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubun-tor/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubun-tor/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/deb/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubun-tor/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubun-tor/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/<DISTRIBUTION>/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubun-to

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *[edit]* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: try to reinstall software center.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a ruff translation.. But this part caught my eye... softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2013-11-10 22:31:00,646 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/utils.py', 201, 'get_title_from_html')'
2013-11-10 22:31:00,645 - root - WARNING - failed to parse: 
Vaguely this is saying you have a file from software center that is not capable of being found.. Possibly deleted, or much out of date